# Is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n+1} (-1)^{n}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I will like to know whether $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n+1} x^{n}, \: x \in \mathbb{R}$ is convergent for $x=\pm1$ or not.
I found the radius of convergence to be $r=1$. So I have to check each ($x=1$ and $x=-1$) case separately. $x=1$ is easy. $x=-1$ is not so easy. **I have used the limit test, M-test, root test, Leibniz test, comparison tes. But none if them work. I do not think I have other tests in my arsenal.**

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Group the terms in pairs and you'll get it right away.

Comment: This question has been asked just yesterday. the same.

Comment: You haven't used that, if a series is convergent then it's terms converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah where?

Comment: @Ty. You were in the right track, so you could just edit your answer.

Comment: @B.Goddard 
I'm not sure what you mean. But by writing it out I get 
$-1/2 + 2/3-3/4+4/5-5/6+...$. Nothing cancels out here.

Comment: Look at Tom's comment, it's they key to answering th quesion.

Comment: @Tom. Thanks ! I did not noticed your answer at first, there was to many comments :D I have solved it. But I should probably proof that it does not convergent to $0$. 

Comment: I HAVE PROOVED THIS. HOW do I close this, so I do not waste peoples time?

Comment: You don't close a question when you had an answer. People can see that the question has an approved answer, so they can avoid it if they want to. Or they can find a better way to answer, if they want to.

Comment: @Ingix
Oh, okay. I did not know that. I thought one should marke it "answered" or something.

Comment: That's what you did, by marking an answer as approved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already noted @Tom explained that, if $\sum_{n\ge0}a_n$ converges, the triangle inequality implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. [Whatever name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) that test has, it proves your series diverges. Indeed$$a_n:=\frac{(-1)^nn}{n+1}\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=1\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\ne0.$$In fact $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ doesn't exist, because the subsequences for even (odd) $n$ have respective limits $1$ ($-1$), which differ. ([That test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MIP8otPXL0) appears to have a name too.)

Comment: Why are you taking the absolute value here: $$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|a_{n}\right|=1
$$

Comment: @Xenusi Because it's an easy way to prove this sequence fails the term test.

Comment: But $\frac{(-1)^{n} n}{n+1}$ and $\frac{ n}{n+1}$ are different. If the first have a limit who says the second have the same limit?

Comment: @Xenusi It's a proof by contradiction that $a_n$ *doesn't* have limit $0$ because if it did then $|a_n|$ *would*.

Comment: I think you have lost me. $a_n$ do not have limit (how do we know this formally) $|a_n|$ har er limit which can be shown.

Answer (score -1):

OK, note that

$$\frac{-n}{n+1} + \frac{n+1}{n+2} = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}.$$

So if you pair up the terms, you get a series with terms less than $1/n^2$.  So the series converges when $x=-1$.

Now if you pair them up the other way, you'll get a series that also converges to a different number.  So now what?